# How to get Aspect Ratio of device in Cocos2d-x?

Tags: cocos2d-x, aspect-ratio

Is there any way to get the aspect ratio of device. For example whether it is 16:9 or 4:3 or 3:2?

I want to exact fit resources for these resolutions. The problem i face is device dont give the exact values for example width/ height of iPhone 4inch is not exactly 16:9 but relatively equal. Is there any way to get the devices aspect ratio?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is pseudo code to get aspect-ratio of the screen. You might need to set `table` has 16:9, 4:3, 3:2, or whatever you want aspect-ratio entries.

```
auto frameSize = Director::getInstance()->getOpenGLView()->getFrameSize();
auto aspectRatio = frameSize.width / frameSize.height;

int aspectRatioType = DEFAULT_ASPECT_RATIO_TYPE;
float closest = FLT_MAX; 
for (const auto& i : table) {
    auto d = fabs(i.aspectRatio - aspectRatio);
    if (d < closest) {
        closest = d;
        aspectRatioType = i.aspectRatioType;
    }
}
return aspectRatioType;
```